# Compare two workbooks, delete matching rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have three workbooks.

One workbook is a list I add to every month, of things I need to delete from a second workbook. I receive a second workbook every month. The second workbook I receive always contains extraneous entries (the number growing every month) and will not be fixed anytime soon. There is no general filter I can make without making the second workbook useless, so I need to be really specific and have a silly cleaning list.

My third workbook is where I run all of my workbook cleaning macros from.

The objective is to compare the entries in column A or B on the first workbook with the entries in column A or B of the second workbook I receive. If any of the entries match, delete the entire row on the second workbook.

I will be doing this once a month for a few hundred lines, and it will be run from a macro assigned to a shape on a third workbook.

Here I am posting some code that lets me open my two files and copy the contents of one of them, but what I need is code that will compare and delete rows on Workbook 2 that match with Workbook 1. My own code to do exactly that is terrible, not worth posting at all.

Code:

```
Sub test()

  Dim strFileName As String
  Dim wbTarget As Workbook
  Dim wbSource As Workbook
  Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
  Dim wsSource As Worksheet

  strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls*),*.xl*", Title:="Open data")

  Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
  Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)

  Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1")

  'to copy from Target - > Source

  wsTarget.Range("B2").Resize(5, 5).Copy wsSource.Range("B2")

  'etc.

End Sub
```

Code, comment and suggestion is greatly appreciated!
Cheers,
Christopher

CODE UPDATE 8:30 AM: This is a new way I am thinking of making things work. I am getting a type mismatch error on the code line `Set Rng = Range("A1:B10000" & LR)`

```
    Sub test()

        Dim strFileName As String
        Dim strFileName2 As String
        Dim wbTarget As Workbook
        Dim wbSource As Workbook
        Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
        Dim wsSource As Worksheet
        Dim LR
        Dim Rng As Range

        strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls*),*.xl*", Title:="Open 'Things Which Have Been Removed'")


        strFileName2 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls*),*.xl*", Title:="Open This Month's Purge List")

        Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
        Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)

        Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set LR = wsSource.UsedRange.Rows

            With wbTarget.Sheets(1)
            Set Rng = Range("A1:B10000" & LR)
            Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(4), Header:=xlNo
        End With

   End Sub
```

Comment: Any experience with MS Access?  You could create a link to both spreadsheets and pull them in as tables.  Then all you need is a SQL DELETE query that says something like DELETE FROM TABLE 2 WHERE EXISTS IN TABLE 1.) This is simplified and wont run, but is close.  Then you can export table 2.  I'd recommend looking into it if you are going to be doing this kind of thing a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, my company has never and will never use access. Too efficient. It would solve a lot of problems though, good idea!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question.

```
Set Rng = Range("A1:B10000" & LR)
```

Should be

```
Set Rng = Range("A1:B" & LR)
```

I would like to help with your other issues, but your description is confusing, this is what I understand; you identify bad information in the second workbook and copy that information from the second workbook to the first workbook, then you want a macro to match what is in the first workbook to the second workbook and delete the rows in the second workbook that match. Question, why don't you delete the rows in the second workbook instead of copying them to the first workbook?

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch, I am going to apply this to my code! 

Sorry for the confusion, let me try to clarify. It's hard to supply just information, especially with no context. So, I have a master excel sheet for macros only. I have one excel sheet that has all of the "bad data" part numbers that I've collected over months. I have another separate sheet that I receive every month that may or may not have some of the "bad data" that I've been collecting. I just want to make sure that whenever I receive this new workbook, all of the data I don't want gets eliminated with a push of a button. Ty!

Answer (score -1):

You can use find method ; after open workbook u can use this code, findind the cell adress u can easily delete it clear command

```
Dim GCell As Range

 Set GCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("yourvariable")
```

Comment: This would also work, yet avoiding ActiveSheet is a good rule I try to follow. It avoids mix-ups between sheets if some piece of code goes wrong or another sheet is selected. I am trying to create a workbook that's pretty hard to mess up. Also, in this case I think I am out of my range of knowledge. I understand that I could find a specific word with this method, but I don't know about all of the entries of part numbers on my Workbook1.